# Splitting strings and then parsing to ints

Tags: c#, .net

This is the exercise I am doing:

Write a program that takes as input a four-digit number in format abcd (e.g. 2011) and performs the following:

•   Calculates the sum of the digits (in our example 2+0+1+1 = 4).

•   Prints on the console the number in reversed order: dcba (in our example 1102).

•   Puts the last digit in the first position: dabc (in our example 1201).

•   Exchanges the second and the third digits: acbd (in our example 2101).

and here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FourDigitNum = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] digits = FourDigitNum.Split();
            int firstDigit = int.Parse(digits[0]);
            int secondDigit = int.Parse(digits[1]);
            int thirdDigit = int.Parse(digits[2]);
            int fourthDigit = int.Parse(digits[3]);
            int sum = firstDigit + secondDigit + thirdDigit + fourthDigit;
            string reversed = digits[3] + digits[2] + digits[1] + digits[0];
            string lastCharFirst = digits[3] + digits[0] + digits[1] + digits[0];
            string exchanged = digits[0] + digits[2] + digits[1] + digits[3];
            Console.WriteLine("The Sum is: {0}", sum);
            Console.WriteLine("The Reversed number is: {0}", reversed);
            Console.WriteLine("The Last Digit is First: {0}", lastCharFirst);
            Console.WriteLine("The Second and Third Digit Exchanged: {0}", exchanged);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get when I use 1100 as input is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was
>   outside the boun ds of the array.    at
>   ConsoleApplication6.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   c:\Users\User1\Document s\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\Program.cs:line 16

Edit: Thank you so much, I misunderstood how Split(); worked. Here is my final working code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string digits = Console.ReadLine();
            int firstDigit = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[0]);
            int secondDigit = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[1]);
            int thirdDigit = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[2]);
            int fourthDigit = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[3]);
            int sum = firstDigit + secondDigit + thirdDigit + fourthDigit;
            Console.WriteLine("The Sum is: {0}", sum);
            Console.WriteLine("The Reversed number is: {3}{2}{1}{0}", firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit, fourthDigit);
            Console.WriteLine("The Last Digit is First: {3}{0}{1}{2}", firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit, fourthDigit);
            Console.WriteLine("The Second and Third Digit Exchanged: {0}{2}{1}{3}", firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit, fourthDigit);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what debugging have you done? Hint: put a breakpoint at `int firstDigit = ...` and look at `digits`...

Comment: Your FourDigitNum.Split() didn't do what you thought it would do

Comment: The test imput I used is 1100

Comment: So how should I do it so I can store each individual digit into an int.

Comment: I assume you are using Visual Studio, is that right? Do you know how to use the debugger? If you step through the code line by line and look at all the local variables at each step, you should be able to see the problem.

Comment: The last value in your `lastCharFirst` is also incorrect. It should be `digits[2]`...just saying ;)

Comment: Check for FourDigitNum.Length to see if you have 4 elements on that array, user input is not always what you need...

Comment: Downvoter, this question shows effort to understand what is going on, provides the error and what the expected result was.  I think a downvote is unfair in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much, I misunderstood how Split(); worked. Here is my final working code:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for `Split`, you are assuming that by doing `Split()` it will split each character into a string array's element. It is not, `Split()` without any parameter will split on White Space characters, and since in your string `1102` you don't have any white space character, you will get back an array of single element. Hence the exception.

Use string as character array, you can access each index and create a reversed string by concatenating characters. Also learn to debug and stepping through the code, that will help you in troubleshooting your code.

As a hint use:

```
int firstDigit = (int) Char.GetNumericValue(FourDigitNum[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

"IndexOutOfRangeException" means that you're trying to access an element of a collection that's out of range.  In this case, the index `1` is out of range for the array `digits`.

You can check to see what's in the array using the debugger.  Conveniently, when you hit an uncaught exception in visual studio, it will normally make a breakpoint for you.

[image: debugger]

<sub>* The "Locals" tab is currently selected, but you can select the "Watch" tag if you want to write your own expression see [Visual Studio Debugging Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)</sub>

As you can see, the `digits` array only contains 1 element, `digits[0]`, which contains your whole input.

As for how to actually get a list of string digits, there are plenty of ways to do it, here is a simple one.

```
string[] digits = FourDigitNum.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Now if you're doing this for school, your teacher might get suspicious of your use of the `Select` statement, but I'll leave figuring another method as an exercise for you.

Comment: Best explanation of a coded issue I've seen all day also `string[] digits = FourDigitNum.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();` does the trick in my opinion as well ..great explanation @SamIam

Answer (score 2):

the problem is in line

```
string[] digits = FourDigitNum.Split();
```

assume you have 1100 as input. you think that this will give [1,1,0,0] but it will give you [1100]

you should just change it to

```
string digits = Console.ReadLine();
```

[string.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will split the string assuming whitespaces as separator.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
string[] digits = FourDigitNum.Split();
```

It returns just an array with just one item. The split does not happen as you intended and that is why you are getting `Index was outside the bounds of the array` error when you are trying to

```
int secondDigit = int.Parse(digits[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding string usage here. A String at its core is also a collection of characters. You can access these characters directly by index.

Your code should look like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string digits = Console.ReadLine();
        int firstDigit = Convert.ToInt32(digits[0]);
        int secondDigit = Convert.ToInt32(digits[1]);
        int thirdDigit = Convert.ToInt32(digits[2]);
        int fourthDigit = Convert.ToInt32(digits[3]);
        int sum = firstDigit + secondDigit + thirdDigit + fourthDigit;
        string reversed = digits[3] + digits[2] + digits[1] + digits[0];
        string lastCharFirst = digits[3] + digits[0] + digits[1] + digits[0];
        string exchanged = digits[0] + digits[2] + digits[1] + digits[3];
        Console.WriteLine("The Sum is: {0}", sum);
        Console.WriteLine("The Reversed number is: {0}", reversed);
        Console.WriteLine("The Last Digit is First: {0}", lastCharFirst);
        Console.WriteLine("The Second and Third Digit Exchanged: {0}", exchanged);
    }
```

[Look here for more information on the String class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your FourDigitNum.Split() didn't do what you thought you wanted.  Instead of splitting out every digit into an array, you end up with an array that has 1 element that is the four digit number.

Change

```
string[] digits = FourDigitNum.Split();
```

To

```
string[] digits = FourDigitNum.Select(digit => digit.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Make sure you have

```
using System.Linq;
```

With your other `using` statments, and the rest of your code can stay the same.

Results:

```
2011
The Sum is: 4
The Reversed number is: 1102
The Last Digit is First: 1202
The Second and Third Digit Exchanged: 2101
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no defined character to split on. You could go thru each character in the string like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string FourDigitNum = Console.ReadLine();
        List<string> digitsList = new List<string>();
        foreach (char c in FourDigitNum)
        {
            digitsList.Add(c.ToString());
        }
        string[] digits = digitsList.ToArray();
        int firstDigit = int.Parse(digits[0]);
        int secondDigit = int.Parse(digits[1]);
        int thirdDigit = int.Parse(digits[2]);
        int fourthDigit = int.Parse(digits[3]);
        int sum = firstDigit + secondDigit + thirdDigit + fourthDigit;
        string reversed = digits[3] + digits[2] + digits[1] + digits[0];
        string lastCharFirst = digits[3] + digits[0] + digits[1] + digits[0];
        string exchanged = digits[0] + digits[2] + digits[1] + digits[3];
        Console.WriteLine("The Sum is: {0}", sum);
        Console.WriteLine("The Reversed number is: {0}", reversed);
        Console.WriteLine("The Last Digit is First: {0}", lastCharFirst);
        Console.WriteLine("The Second and Third Digit Exchanged: {0}", exchanged);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FourDigitNum = Console.ReadLine();
            int firstDigit = int.Parse(FourDigitNum.SubString(0,1));
            int secondDigit = int.Parse(FourDigitNum.SubString(1,1));
            int thirdDigit = int.Parse(FourDigitNum.SubString(2,1));
            int fourthDigit = int.Parse(FourDigitNum.SubString(3,1));
            int sum = firstDigit + secondDigit + thirdDigit + fourthDigit;
            string reversed = fourthDigit.ToString()  + thirdDigit.ToString()  + secondDigit.ToString()  + firstDigit.ToString();
            string lastCharFirst = fourthDigit.ToString() + firstDigit.ToString() + secondDigit.ToString() + firstDigit.ToString();
            string exchanged = firstDigit.ToString() + thirdDigit.ToString() + secondDigit.ToString() + fourthDigit.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("The Sum is: {0}", sum);
            Console.WriteLine("The Reversed number is: {0}", reversed);
            Console.WriteLine("The Last Digit is First: {0}", lastCharFirst);
            Console.WriteLine("The Second and Third Digit Exchanged: {0}", exchanged);
        }
    }
}
```

I have not checked it on machine, but i think it should work. Try to execute it once.

Answer (score -1):

You are hard coding the length of the string being input, but doing .Split() only creates a single item in the array, not four.

You can split the string into a char Array .ToCharArray() to create an array with each digit as its own item in the array.

Comment: Not exactly correct. .Split() does in fact split into an array. However in their case with `1102` as input, it will only give `digits[0] = 1102` and nothing else on the rest.

Comment: Doing split() in this example is creating a single item in the array, how is that incorrect?

Comment: A single item is not a single item array.

Comment: `doing .Split() only creates a single item.`, You should clarify as to why and state that it is only in this case. Which I why I said it wasn't wrong, I said it wasn't exactly correct.

Comment: this will not do anything more than return `1102` look at @SamIam answer and explanation and you will see how and why his example works for the OP case